# How to read value of custom attribute of multiple formats?

Tags: android, android-studio

[related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179111/how-to-access-custom-attribute-with-multiple-formats)

We can define custom attribute of multiple types.

```
<declare-styleable name="RoundedImageView">
    <attr name="cornerRadius" format="dimension|fraction"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

And I want to use it in the following way

```
<RoundedImageView app:cornerRadius="30dp"/>
<RoundedImageView app:cornerRadius="20%"/>
```

How to read the value out of it?

---

API level 21 provided an API [`TypedArray.getType(index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getType(int))

```
int type = a.getType(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_cornerRadius);
if (type == TYPE_DIMENSION) {
    mCornerRadius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_cornerRadius, 0);
} else if (type == TYPE_FRACTION) {
    mCornerRadius = a.getFraction(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_cornerRadius, 1, 1, 0);
}
```

I guess this is the recommended solution.

But how to do it with lower API level? Do I have to use `try catch`?

Or maybe just define two attributes... `cornerRadius` and `cornerRadiusPercentage`... I'm going to miss `border-radius` in CSS.

Comment: `TypedArray.getValue(...)` + `TypedValue.type` ?

Comment: @Selvin I'm trying your solution. I think it will work. Thanks.

Comment: @Selvin You can post an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @Selvin's comment. You can use `TypedArray.getValue(...)` + `TypedValue.type`. You can find the type constants [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#TYPE_FLOAT)

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
a.getValue(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_cornerRadius, tv);
if (tv.type == TYPE_DIMENSION) {
    mCornerRadius = tv.getDimension(getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
} else if (tv.type == TYPE_FRACTION) {
    mCornerRadius = tv.getFraction(1, 1);
    mUsePercentage = true;
}
```

Comment: why not `mCornerRadius  = tv.getFraction(1,1);` and `mCornerRadius = tv.getDimension(getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());` ?